# Mocking with Nock, DELETE

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, supertest, nock

How would I mock a delete with nock

this is what I have done so far:

```
var nock = require('nock');
var request = require('supertest')("http://localhost:8080");
var expect = require('chai').expect;
describe('Mocked tests for server components', function(){

var mockRequest = nock('http://localhost:8080');
it('Should Delete /user/removeuserskills', function(req, res){
    mockRequest
    .delete('/user/removeuserskills',{
      'email':'Johny@gmail.com',
      'user_skill':'accoutant'
    })
    .reply(200,{
     'status':200,
     'message': '200: Successfully deleted skill'
      });
    request
    .delete('/user/removeuserskills')
    .end(function(err, res){
      expect(res.body.status).to.equal(200);
    });

  });
});
```

I have trouble demonstrating how I would first add that user with that skill and then delete it.

Right now with this code, I get an undefined body.

EDIT:

Actually I am getting

```
{ Error: Nock: No match for request:

 { method:"DELETE", 
   url: "http://localhost:8080/user/removeuserskills"
 }
}
```

Comment: I dont get the reply back.

Answer (score 1):

How I do it is using their `.intercept` API. That means your code should look like this:

```
   mockRequest
    .intercept('/user/removeuserskills', 'DELETE', {
      'email':'Johny@gmail.com',
      'user_skill':'accoutant'
    })
    .reply(200,{
     'status':200,
     'message': '200: Successfully deleted skill'
    });
```